# Hidden text isn't becoming visible?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Javascript to make hidden text become visible once the condition is met.

Here's my Javascript code:

```
    var userAnswer = prompt("You and your best friend, John, are out camping in a remote forest. After getting to your location and setting down the supplies, you and John decide you should you explore the surrounding area. Do you want to split up or stick together?");

if(userAnswer === "split up") {
    document.getElementById(test).style.visibility="visible";
} else {
    document.getElementById(test2).style.visibility="visible";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>

 <p id="test" style="visibility:hidden;"> Testing!</p>

 <p id="test2" style="visibility:hidden;"> Testing 2!</p>

 </div>
```

The text isn't becoming visible, though. Any suggestions?

Comment: It (document.getElementById call) should be with `'test'` and `'test2'` as arguments. with quotes around the strings.

Comment: Woow I feel so stupid now, haha. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Since you are targeting an ID within the code you have to signify that with the `"` around the name of the id:

SCRIPT:

```
if(userAnswer === "split up") {
document.getElementById("test").style.visibility="visible";
} else {
    document.getElementById("test2").style.visibility="visible";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how I forgot to add quotes around the id. Thanks for pointing that out